# Moving messages between destinations in a WebSphere Application Server ND 7 system

Tags: websphere-7

This relates to the management of messages in a WebSphere Application Server ND 7.0 system. We are looking for a robust tool for viewing / moving / deleting messages between (JMS) destinations. In particular we need advise about a tool that can help us efficiently manage large number of messages between destinations.  Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using SIBus (aka WebSphere platform default messaging) as JMS provider, you may want to have a look at [IBM Service Integration Bus Destination Handler](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021439).

Answer (score 0):

A small notice from my side. I got the tool (version 1.1.5) to work quickly (read, export to file, import from file, move), but I discovered that the tool is of limited use.

I could not find a setting that will export the full message body for message that is queued on a JMS subscription. When I export messages from a JMS subscription it only fetches 1024 bytes of data.

It did however export the full message on a regular queue destination. However when I put it back and exported it again, there  were small differences as evidenced by Beyond Compare file comparison.

The tool looks promising with scripts that can be exported but it is necessary to test your use case scenario.

The tool could use a revision and better testing before being put on the internet.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You may try to post your comments/issues here - [IBM Service Integration Bus Destination Handler - Q&A](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=6a8691d9-d72f-4aaa-bf52-a670ee1fe8b2)